# Postgres database drop is very slow

Tags: postgresql, mocha.js, node-postgres

So the situation I'm running into is when I run `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS <database_name>` on an empty database it takes roughly 20-25 seconds to drop it.

A little context...I'm using mocha to run unit tests, in my `before` hook I create a test database, in my `beforeEach` hooks I fill the database with test data from a SQL file, my `afterEach` hook empties the tables using truncate/cascade and also resets sequences, and the `after` hook drops the database.

I'm just wondering why it takes so long to drop a database that was already emptied with the `afterEach` hook.

Also if I run just one small suite of tests it doesn't take long at all but the more tests I include the longer it takes to drop the database at the very end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `DROP DATABASE` triggers a [checkpoint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-checkpoint.html), flushing dirty buffers to disk (for every database on the server, not just the one you're dropping).   Try running your own `CHECKPOINT` command immediately before the `DROP`, and see if it absorbs some of the cost (won't speed up the overall process, but may help to diagnose the issue).

Comment: This actually is a HUGE help thanks for the response. That is exactly what was causing the slow `DROP DATABASE`